# Why this argument does not prove powers of prime are always primary?

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I know this lemma

> Let $P, Q$ be ideals in a commutative ring $R$, and suppose:
>
> - $P$ is maximal
> - $\sqrt Q = P$
>
> Then $Q$ is $P$-primary.

Then, as $\sqrt{P^n} = P$, every such power is primary. On the other hand, I know that if $P$ is prime, $P^n$ needs not be primary, since counterexamples are known.

What's going on then?

Answer (score 1):

The trouble here is that $P$ is assumed to be *maximal*, not just prime. Hence the argument does not apply to arbitrary prime ideals since maximality is a strictly stronger property than primality.

Comment: Did you just answer your own question after 1 minute? You might want to consider deleting it.

Comment: It is good practice if I understand correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer
Anyway I put it here to make it Google friendly for future me and other people as well.

Comment: I'd agree if there was an actual question being answered. This is just "Oops, didn't read the lemma carefully."